# How to add file not found exception to this code?

Tags: java, error-handling, jakarta-mail, java-io

I use this code to send mail using java. In here i attach a pdf file to mail. if file not found i want to throw and file not found exception.How to do it?

```
    try{
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiver));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    // Create the message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    // Fill the message
    messageBodyPart.setText("hai");
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    //Attachement
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String filename = "file";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
    message.setContent(multipart);
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    try{
        transport.connect(host,from,password);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException err){
        String errMsg = "Authentication fails when sending mail. Sent failed to " + receiver;
        log.error(errMsg,err);
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException(errMsg + err.getMessage());
    }
    transport.send(message);
} catch (MessagingException re) {
    String localizedError = "Unexpected error occurred at Email client. Sent failed to:" + receiver + ". ";
    log.error(localizedError + re.getLocalizedMessage(), re);
    throw new MessagingException(localizedError + re.getLocalizedMessage(), re);
}
```

This is the code i want to add file not found exception

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious here, your code will throw *some* exception when it tries to use the file and cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that Either FileDataSource or DataHandler would do that, but if not, just add:

```
new FileInputStream(filename).close();
```

before passing the filename argument to FileDataSource.
which will throw that exception for you.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean?

```
if(!new File(filename).exists()) throw new FileNotFoundException(filename);
```

I would have though any function which reads the file should throw this anyway, so I don't see the need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc for [FileDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/glasgow/javadocs/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html) for the input/output stream methods:

> This method will return an ...Stream representing the the data and
>   will throw an IOException if it can not do so. This method will return
>   a new instance of InputStream with each invocation.

You'll need to handle more than `FileNotFoundException`, note. What happens if you're passed a directory, or an unreadable file ? `IOException` will encapsulate all of these.